# How to add custom mapbox zoom buttons in react?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox

I am trying to create custom zoom buttons but can't find a working solution

```
const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(9)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (map.current) return
    map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: 'myStlyeURL',
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: zoom,
    })
  })

<div className="relative h-[220px] overflow-hidden">
  <div ref={mapContainer} className="map-container h-[220px]" />
</div>
<button onClick={() => setZoom(zoom - 1)}>-</button>
<button onClick={() => setZoom(zoom + 1)}>+</button>
```